# Find My SO Answers: Community Wiki only

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, community-wiki

Is there any way to search for my SO answers that are either community wiki or in a question marked community wiki?  I'm looking for an Answer I provided recently that I know was community wiki...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the top right search box, type:

- [user:me wiki:1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search#advanced-search) (self)
- user:{id} wiki:1    (others)

Comment: Is there a guide to the syntax of the search command?

Comment: @Lord.Quackstar: and an advanced search option